# -1.#IND  без деления на 0

Tags: c, c++

Прочитал, что такая ошибка при делении на ноль, но у меня нет никакого деления, самая простая программа:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

float getMax(float d1, float d2, float d3)
{
    if (d1 < d2)
    {
        if (d2 < d3) return d3;
        else return d2;
    }
    if (d1 > d3) return d1;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int arr[3][3] = {};
    double x1[100], x2[100], x3[100],d1(0),d2(0),d3(0),e;

    x1[0] = 0;
    x2[0] = 0;
    x3[0] = 0;
    cout<<getMax(1.0,0.1,1.2);
    cin.get();

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное, `return d3;` в конце `getMax()` надо добавить.

В вашем же случае -- `getMax(1.0,0.1,1.2)` возвращается *неизвестно что*. Вот при преобразованиях `float` (тип результата функции) в строку символов внутри `cout` неприятность и произошла...

Answer (score 3):

У функции getMax есть одна проблема - она иногда может завершаться без return. Что именно она возвратит в этом случае - никто не знает (точнее, что там окажется в регистре процессора или ячейке памяти, как компилятор сделает код).

Так как функция должна найти максимум из трех элементов, то можно воспользоваться функцией max, которую применить дважды:

```
float getMax(float d1, float d2, float d3)
{
    return max(d1, max(d2, d3));
}
```

Саму функцию max можно взять готовую или просто написать.

Comment: Точно, спасибо.